# visual_effect after replace_html not working in rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rjs

In learning ruby on rails I've created a blog site. When the user adds a post via AJAX, the following rjs gets called:

```
page.replace_html 'posts',  :partial => @posts
page.visual_effect :Highlight, 'post_' + @post.id.to_s
```

However, the highlight isn't happening.. neither is any sort of effect even a hide.

Clues:

- It works if I just do an insert_html
  for just the new post    (but I want
  to update the whole list    of posts
  at this time)
- If I hard code the id to the next id in the sequence, it doesn't work on the post, but it does work on the next post. { ex.. hardcode post_100... no highlight on submit 100, highlight 100 on submit 101 }
- Alert shows that 'post_' + @post.id.to_s is what is expected ( post_100, etc )

Any ideas or debugging suggestions?

Thanks,
Orlando

Comment: After a post is added, inspect your page using something like firebug to see the actual of the div containing new post.  My guess is it's not post_100 but something else.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it appears as desired. It's consistent between what Firebug shows and what an alert displays:

    page.replace_html 'posts',  :partial => @posts
    page.visual_effect :Highlight, 'post_' + @post.id.to_s
    page << "alert('post_" + @post.id.to_s + "');";

Comment: That alert is only checking that id.to_s is "100", not that the partial contains something with id="posts_100".  After you get the result back, does $('posts_100') in the Firebug console return anything? Or, you could render_to_string/logger.debug your partial  to see if it's got the correct id in it.

Comment: Yup, $('posts_100') returns as expected in the Firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Can you alert the innerHTML of the $("post_#{@post.id}") before the visual_effect.

Does firebug give you an error when it gets to the visual_effect?

Can you do something else, like an alert after the visual_effect line?

Have you got the required js files included?

Comment: Great suggestions.. I'm sure the required js is included because other visual effects are working.  I didn't notice any errors in firebug and I didn't notice anything amiss with the HTML upon visual inspection, but I didn't try the alerts. However since my last post I decided to do away with reliance on RJS, and have everything working great using a different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer to the problem, but I have since done away with reliance on rjs. Instead I'm following the pattern outlined here

http://blog.solnic.eu/2007/10/30/why-javascript-helpers-in-rails-are-evil

And now all effects are working as expected. Note that I did get the effect working when comments were added using effectively the same code that should have been working here, so I'm fairly convinced there was just some sort of weird operator error going on.